# Creating new object from existing object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, javascript-objects

I've been at this for a while and can't figure out what I have and how to work with it.

When I use `console.log`, I get this back:

```
description:"Some text here"
id:1234
location:Array(1)
name:"Some Name"
tags:
Array(7)
0:Object
name:"Landmark"
public_id:"landmark"
__proto__
1:Object
name:"Park"
public_id:"park"
__proto__
```

I'm looking to get something like this:

```
{id:1234,tags:[landmark,park]}
```

I can get the `id` part fine with this:

```
var thePlaces=[];
$.each(data, function(index, val) {
       thePlaces.push({
                id:val.id
            })
            })
```

How do I go about adding the tags to the respective `id` now?

Comment: your object seems to represent what you want already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate the `tags` (an array) for each `data` to get the tag names.
So another loop inside the loop which iterates the `data`.

```
var thePlaces=[];
$.each(data, function(index, val) {

  var tagNames=[];

  $.each(val.tags, function(i,tagVal){
    tagNames.push(tagVal.name)
  }

  thePlaces.push({
    id:val.id,
    tags: tagNames
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't quite what I needed. The tags are still in an array and I was looking for more like this: `{id:1234,tags:["landmark","park"]}` instead of `{id:1234,tags:[0:"landmark",1:"park"]}` (which is what this gives me now)

Comment: That `0:` and `1:` are showing when you `JSON.stringify` the object. An array **HAS TO HAVE** a key. It may be an integer of a string (in associative array). The object is valid as it is right now.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Array#map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=control) to create a new array based on another array:

```
// map main array
var thePlaces= data.map(function(item){
    // map location array to get tags array
    var tags = item.location.map(function(loc){
         return loc.name;
    });
    // new object to return for each item in "data"
    return {
       id: item.id,
       tags: tags
    };    
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't quite what I needed. The tags are still in an array and I was looking for more like this: `{id:1234,tags:["landmark","park"]}` instead of `{id:1234,tags:[0:"landmark",1:"park"]}` (which is what this gives me now)

Comment: provide actual sample of data, not what you see in console. Hard to manipulate that back into real data structure to create working demo

Comment: I'd love to do that, but somehow I'm having trouble with getting that. I'm not entirely sure what the data type is and how to get it out in "raw" format. I've always struggled with that for some reason. Suggestions?

Comment: worst case can log it as json using `JSON.stringify()`